# Float display 0 number after 1.5

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a float that adds numbers and its not displaying all the decimal points i wish for example i have 1.25 add 1.25 as a float and it shows as 1.5. How can i have it display as 1.50 for example?

Comment: How are you "displaying" the number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <cstdio>
/* ... */
printf("%.02f", f);
```

See the documentation for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).

Comment: `f` = float. `.` = pad decimal places. `0` = pad with zeros. `2` = pad up to 2 decimal places. Take a look at [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) for more.

Comment: Okay i got it! I thought there was another thing i could use instead of flota but i assume this is the only way?

Comment: @mystycs, not the only way, also check [Mysticial's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699502/float-display-0-number-after-1-5/7699526#7699526).

Comment: It says invalid conversion from int to const character.

Comment: @mystycs, you'd put your float variable there. You said you were using floats, right?

Comment: Yes it works! It actually worked without including cstdio haha

Comment: @mystycs, if it worked without including `cstdio`, then it's probably provided by the compiler. Always include `cstdio` when using `printf()` in C++, for reasons of compatibility.

Comment: Yeah it printed out two numbers for some reason -____- let me try.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, you can do it like this:

```
cout << setprecision(2) << f << endl;
```

EDIT:

This answer isn't completely correct. See comments.

This sets the total precision to 2 digits. (Not digits after the decimal place.)

Comment: I tried that too i got some compiler error do i have to include something?

Comment: Yes: `#include <iomanip>`. The full documentation is here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/

Comment: Shouldn't it be `setprecision(3)` to get 2 decimal places? Not sure if it adds trailing zeros i.e. 1.5 => 1.50

Comment: @another.anon.coward: I think you're right, it's total precision, not after the decimal place. I'll keep my answer up for reference, but it's not correct.

Comment: @Mysticial: Yes Sir! But using `fixed` notation along with the `setprecision` seems to work. Bad idea?

Comment: @another.anon.coward: That does seem to work: (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Mystical solution, you can try `fixed` formatting:

```
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << f << endl;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `%.2f` as a format string.